# Launch Google Maps and Show a Pin in a specific Location action not working anymore

Tags: google-maps

According to the google map [api docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) to launch Google Maps in a new browser window to show a pin using latitude/longitude coordinates is

```
https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=47.5951518,-122.3316393
```

[Expected result as per the api docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GATgz.png)

but instead displays the error message

> Google Maps can't find 47.5951518,-122.3316393

Any suggestions for the correct way of using this api?

Answer (score 0):

I typed your search string above in my browser URL and it works fine. Google Maps appeared for the desired area with the required pin. Please retry and make sure Google Maps services is up.

Comment: Oh i just realized that if i run this in chrome-incognito it works fine. Seems like if i am logged into my google account the result differs.